# Access property value as string literal in PHP

Tags: php, object, abstract-class

Okay, im relearning php for a small home project and run into a problem so heres a quick one for all u php experts:

I have build an abstract class which should access properties of YQL Yahoo returned JSON objects decoded to PHP objects. Lets say I want to access the property `id` then I do like this right:

```
print($phpObject->id);  // Okay
```

But I want to be able to access the property in a more abstract manner, ie something like this:

```
$propertyName = 'id';
print($phpObject[$propertyName]); 
print($phpObject["id"]);
```

But none of the above is working - I am sure for obvious reasons, but me not beeing PHP expert I am having a hard time figurring out this call. Please help me here.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
$propertyName = 'id';

print($phpObject->{$propertyName});
```

Comment: Just as a sidenote - is there not an error in example 2 in this php documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/sdo.sample.getset.php ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [ArrayObject](http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayobject.php) to access it like an array.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood what you were asking. I'll leave this here as a point of interest, though.